# Adding a dynamically-named event listener

Tags: javascript, dynamic, onclicklistener

I am trying to create a configurable button bar, and add `onclick` event listeners to each button. I need the functions to be dynamically assigned, with the names provided by the button's `data-function` attribute.

```
…
<div class="button-set">
  <span class="function-button" data-function="func1"></span>
  <span class="function-button" data-function="func2"></span>
</div>
…
```

And the script:

```
window.onload = function (){
  var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("function-button");
  for (var i=0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    var b = btns[i];
    b.addEventListener("click", ?????, false);
  }
}

function func1() { … }
function func2() { … }
```

So, what should go in `?????` so that the correct functions are added to the `onclick` event for each button?

I want this without jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `func1` and `func2` are global functions,

```
b.addEventListener("click", window[b.getAttributte('data-function')], false);
// Or, in new browsers:
b.addEventListener("click", window[b.dataset.function], false);
```

If they aren't global, you should declare them like this:

```
var functions = {
    func1: function () { … },
    func2: function () { … }
}
b.addEventListener("click", functions[b.dataset.function], false);
```

You could use evil `eval` instead, but better avoid it (slower and injection vulnerable):

```
b.addEventListener("click", eval(b.dataset.function), false);
```